# Git fetch new branch failed

Tags: git, github

A new branch, AAA, is created based on master, now I want to pull/fetch into my local machine, failed. how to do it ?

Please note that the directories are different. I want to pull AAA into app folder. what is right steps to pull a new branch ?

```
--in app/myproject
    $ git remote show origin
    Password for 'https://xxx@ibgit.com:8443':
    * remote origin
      Fetch URL: https://xxx@ibgit.com:8443/scm/s.git
      Push  URL: https://xxx@ibgit.com:8443/scm/s.git
      HEAD branch: master
      Remote branches:
        M-10125                                 tracked
        feature/AAA                      new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
        master                                     tracked
        release-0.0.0.0                            tracked

      Local branch configured for 'git pull':
        master merges with remote master
      Local ref configured for 'git push':
        master pushes to master (local out of date)

    -- in app directory
    $ git fetch  feature/AAA
    fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

    $ git fetch AAA
    fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

    $ git fetch origin/AAA
    fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Thanks

Comment: and all the outputs are from the same directory?

Comment: yes, it is using same directory.

Comment: If everything is configured "as default" and you're not changing directories between `git remote show...` and `git fetch` then `git fetch` (w/o any arguments) should do the Right Thing!

Comment: use 'git fetch origin feature/AAA'

Comment: git fetch origin feature/AAA, same error

Comment: So you cloned the repository from `https://xxx@ibgit.com:8443/scm/s.git`, did `cd s`, did `git remote show...` and then directly `git fetch...` ?

Comment: @user1615666 can you attach a screenshot of your terminal here?

Comment: sorry, the folder is different. Please see my updates.

Comment: so just move into myproject using **cd myproject** and these commands would be working.

Comment: That's not the way git works. git is not subversion! Maybe `git worktree` can help. (`git help worktree`)

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding of the branch concept. You should stay at the same root directory (your repository folder) - when you switch between branches the entire directory (in your filesystem) change it state.

Comment: @Priyam, run the comman successfully. but it just changed to Tracked. when I list all local branch, it is not there.

Comment: @user1615666 since git fetch has already been run, you can now use 'git checkout feature/AAA', it will now be seen in 'git branch'. To notice the branches you can checkout use 'git branch -v -a'

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `.git` folder is not found.
If the folder exists, perhaps check the rights on the folder, if it does not exist, do `git init`

Comment: But then `git remote show...` wouldn't work either, would it ?

Comment: ah, thats true, did not notice that.

Comment: sorry, the folder is different. Please see my updates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Git repository is inside `app/project`.

Please try to locate where your `.git` directory is. The `.git` directory is usually at the root of the project.

You either need to run Git commands in `app/project` or you can create a new repo by removing `app/project/.git` and running `git init` in `app`.